# Visual Studio 2019 cant build Tizen project

Tags: c#, sdk

I have installed Tizen studio 3.5 for Visual Studio 2019 but I cant create Tizen project. I got error unable to find Tizen.NET.SDK in C://Program Files\dotnet\3.100\sdks\Tizen.Net.Sdk\sdk. How do I fix this error?[image]

Comment: This seems like the Tizen SDK wasn't correctly installed. Or installed for an older version. Go check the `C://Program Files\dotnet\3.100\sdks\Tizen.Net.Sdk\sdk` folder, and others in the subfolder `C://Program Files\dotnet`

Comment: Tizen.Net.sdk file is missing from C://Program Files\dotnet\3.100\sdks\Tizen.Net.Sdk\sdk and C://Program Files\dotnet. I installed Tizen  studio 3.5 for Visual Studio 2019. Should I uninstall Tizen studio 3.5 and install 3.6 instead?

Comment: Uninstall Tizen studio and Visual Studio 2019 and reinstalled it didnt work. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Lost nearly a day on the same issue.

```
Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources
```

Under `Available Package Sources` add `Name: whatever`, `Source: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`.

That should work.